# How to resolve properties file when trying to use sliding menu

Tags: android

I have unzipped and imported SlidingMenu-master.zip in Eclipse IDE.

And then I have created a new project where I have added a library named folder(It was created when I imported the SlidingMenu-master unzipped folder) as a library dependency in this new project.

Now I am facing an issue:

```
*Failed to load properties file for project 'MyFirstSlide'
*Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PropertiesFileEditor: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MyFirstSlide/project.properties'.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Here, MyFirstSlide is my project name

Comment: Hello add the android.support.v4 jar to your project if not exist,